# QT conflict between Anaconda and MacPort

Tags: qt, anaconda

I'm on OS X 10.10.4 with Macports and Anaconda (condo 3.15.1).
During the process of building the robotic simulator ARGoS,

https://github.com/ilpincy/argos3

we ran into runtime 'qt' issues running the ARGoS examples.

[FATAL] Can't load library "/usr/local/lib/argos3/libargos3plugin_simulator_epuck.dylib" even after trying to add extensions for shared library (dylib) and module library (so): 
/usr/local/lib/argos3/libargos3plugin_simulator_epuck.dylib: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/argos3/libargos3plugin_simulator_epuck.dylib, 1): Library not loaded: @rpath/./libQtOpenGL.4.dylib

I learned that cmake found 'qt' within Anaconda which had runtime problems.
-- Found Qt4: /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.6")

Next, I installed qt4-mac:

```
sudo port install qt4-mac

---> Computing dependencies for qt4-mac
---> Fetching archive for qt4-mac
---> Attempting to fetch qt4-mac-4.8.7_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2 from http://packages.macports.org/qt4-mac
---> Attempting to fetch qt4-mac-4.8.7_0.darwin_14.x86_64.tbz2.rmd160 from http://packages.macports.org/qt4-mac
---> Installing qt4-mac @4.8.7_0
---> Activating qt4-mac @4.8.7_0
NOTE: Qt database plugins for mysql55, postgresql91, and sqlite2 are NOT installed by this port; they are installed by qt4-mac-*-plugin instead.
---> Cleaning qt4-mac
---> Updating database of binaries
---> Scanning binaries for linking errors 
---> No broken files found.
```

When I installed 'qt' with Macports, ipython qtconsole broke.

```
David-Laxers-MacBook-Pro:build_simulator davidlaxer$ ipython qtconsole
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/bin/ipython", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
    return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
    super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
    self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
    return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
    return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
    subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
    module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/qt/console/qtconsoleapp.py", line 50, in <module>
    from IPython.external.qt import QtCore, QtGui
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/external/qt.py", line 23, in <module>
    QtCore, QtGui, QtSvg, QT_API = load_qt(api_opts)
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/external/qt_loaders.py", line 277, in load_qt
    result = loaders[api]()
  File "/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/external/qt_loaders.py", line 184, in import_pyqt4
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtSvg
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so, 2): Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /Users/davidlaxer/anaconda/lib//libxml2.2.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib//libiconv.2.dylib
```

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Clarification: running ARGoS examples failed due to run-time issues with QT.  Anaconda worked properly until I installed qt4-mac with Macports.

Comment: SSH is also failing: dyld: Symbol not found: _CGLGetCurrentContext
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
 in /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
Trace/BPT trap: 5